# ACRA can't send customHttpSender to Acrarium

Tags: android, acra

I need to modify the report sends to Acrarium, so I use HttpSender. I have tried using ReportSender instead of HttpSender but the result is the same: report is not send to Acrarium. It works fine using the default settings(without SenderFactory::class).

This is MyApplication class:

```
@AcraCore(
    buildConfigClass = BuildConfig::class,
    reportContent = [ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE],
    reportSenderFactoryClasses = [SenderFactory::class]
)
@AcraHttpSender(
    uri = "http://localhost:port/report",
    basicAuthLogin = "..........",
    basicAuthPassword = "..........,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST
)
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        ACRA.init(this)
    }
}
```

My CustomHttpSender:

```
class CustomSender(config: CoreConfiguration, method: Method = Method.POST, type: StringFormat? = null)
    : HttpSender(config, method, type) {

    override fun send(context: Context, report: CrashReportData) {
        try {
            report.put(
                ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
                report.getString(ReportField.PHONE_MODEL) + getAdditionalInfo()
            )

            println("Report: \n" + report.getString(ReportField.PHONE_MODEL))
//            sendHttpRequests(config, context, mMethod, mType.matchingHttpContentType, login, password, httpConfig.connectionTimeout,
//                httpConfig.socketTimeout, httpConfig.httpHeaders, reportAsString, reportUrl, uris)

            Log.e("YourOwnSender", report.toJSON())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

    override fun sendHttpRequests(configuration: CoreConfiguration, context: Context, method: Method,
        contentType: String, login: String?, password: String?, connectionTimeOut: Int, socketTimeOut: Int,
        headers: MutableMap<String, String>?, content: String, url: URL, attachments: MutableList<Uri>
    ) {
    }

    fun getAdditionalInfo(): String {
        return " ABC-001"
    }
}
```

My SenderFactory:

```
@AutoService(ReportSenderFactory::class)
class SenderFactory: ReportSenderFactory {
    override fun create(context: Context, config: CoreConfiguration): ReportSender {
        return CustomSender(config, HttpSender.Method.POST, StringFormat.JSON)
    }

    override fun enabled(config: CoreConfiguration): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

The logcat is the same between using the default setting and CustomSender:

```
2021-02-26 10:55:05.163 1448-1448/? I/xample.acrates: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-02-26 10:55:05.330 1448-1448/? E/xample.acrates: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-02-26 10:55:05.628 1448-1448/com.example.acratest I/ACRA: ACRA is enabled for com.example.acratest, initializing...
2021-02-26 10:55:05.774 1448-1448/com.example.acratest E/xample.acrates: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-02-26 10:55:05.853 1448-1448/com.example.acratest W/xample.acrates: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-02-26 10:55:05.854 1448-1448/com.example.acratest W/xample.acrates: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-02-26 10:55:05.952 1448-1525/com.example.acratest E/xample.acrates: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-02-26 10:55:05.999 1448-1495/com.example.acratest I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 4a00b69, I4e7e888065
    Build Date                       : 04/09/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.26.06.00
    Local Branch                     : mybranche95ae4c8-d77f-f18d-a9ef-1458d0b52ae8
    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-02-26 10:55:05.999 1448-1495/com.example.acratest I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 8.0.5 AArch64
2021-02-26 10:55:06.003 1448-1495/com.example.acratest I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME: 0x005ff066
2021-02-26 10:55:06.020 1448-1495/com.example.acratest W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
```

There's a difference in tab Run.

The default settings without SenderFactory::class:
[image: The default settings without SenderFactory::class]

With SenderFactory:
[image: With SenderFactory]

How do I send the modified report to Acrarium?

--------------- EDIT ---------------

I only need to add one line:

> super.send(context, report)

```
override fun send(context: Context, report: CrashReportData) {
    try {
        report.put(
            ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
            report.getString(ReportField.PHONE_MODEL) + getAdditionalInfo()
        )
        Log.e("YourOwnSender", report.toJSON())
        super.send(context, report)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw ReportSenderException(
            "Error while sending JSON report via Http POST",
            e
        )
    }

}
```

And I don't need to override fun sendHttpRequests.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. Is `ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("myKey", "myValue");` not sufficient for you?

Comment: Sadly, no. I need more information in Acrarium's "Reports" dashboard - "Device" column as I use ACRA for internal application and all devices have same model.
What I need is either a new column in Acrarium's "Reports" dashboard or modify the current information displayed on that list. 
The purpose is for filtering.

Comment: I think the way to go is to implement a `Collector` as described here: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Custom-Extensions Does not have a straight forward example though

Comment: Probably something similar to this: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/acra-core/src/main/java/org/acra/collector/DeviceIdCollector.kt
By setting the order, you should be able to override the existing value

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always call super when you're overriding methods.

Your Sender overrides two methods without calling super methods, essentially removing the functionality.

You'll also want to disable the default sender when registering your own.

Comment: Calling the super after modifying the data works for me. Thank you so much!